# Enter UK with Article 10 without EEA Family Permit

Tags: resident-permit

I am a family member of EU citizen and holding Resident Card with Article 10.

I know that I don't need visa to enter UK.
However, after I enter UK with Article 10 Resident Card, can I apply UK Resident Card straight away?
Or, do I have to apply for EEA Family Permit before I enter UK?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have an EEA family permit to apply for a UK residence card.  You can enter with your non-UK Article 10 card and then apply for the UK residence card, assuming your EEA national family member is a "qualified person" in the UK (residing there and working, self-employed, studying, or self-sufficient).

Comment: @Soo you can enter the UK if your husband travels with you.  You cannot apply for a UK residence card unless your husband is a qualified person.

Comment: what if my husband will travel with me? I am from Visa-free country, will i have to show Uk custom my Maltese Resident Card? because my friend told me that if i come to Uk with Visitor Visa, then i cannot change my status. thank you

Comment: @Soo your friend is incorrect. Legally, your rights under the EEA regulations are available to you even if you entered as a visitor. But you should indeed show your resident card when you enter; otherwise you might later get in trouble for deception (that is, entering as a visitor when you didn't actually intend to visit, but to remain).